# Winow.setInterval js not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use`setInterval` for a javascript function of mine to be called every 5 seconds. Here is what I have for code:

```
<head>                             
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>     

  <link href="@routes.Assets.at("bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>     
  <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/patientmonitor.js")"/>                             

  <script type="text/javascript">             
      window.setInterval("myFunction()",1000);                     
  </script>                                              
</head>
```

I know the function is being loaded in to the window, because I can call it via `window.myFunction()` and it performs as expected.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setInterval`.

Comment: Use `window.setInterval(myFunction, 5000);`

Comment: If you want the `myFunction` function to be called every 5 seconds, why are you passing `1000` to `setInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code this `<script>` has not closing tag but it is being self closed which is wrong

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/patientmonitor.js")"/>
```

that's why `setInterval` code is not executing.

Your code have quote `""` problem also.

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at('javascripts/patientmonitor.js')"/> 
//-----------------------------^convert it into single quote-^
<link href="@routes.Assets.at('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction (){
    alert("your code here");
}
window.setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myInterval = setInterval(function() { myFunction() }", 5000);
```